# Show full path when using options

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, ls

I often use this list command in Unix (AIX / KSH):

`ls -Artl`

It displays the files as this:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup   0 Apr  2 11:59 test1.txt`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup   0 Apr  2 11:59 test2.txt`

I would like to modify the command such a way that the full path of the file is displayed. For example:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup   0 Apr  2 11:59 /usr/test1.txt`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup   0 Apr  2 11:59 /usr/test2.txt`

Any ideas?

I found several resolution methods using `pwd` or `find` but - as far as I see - this does not work work if I want to keep the `ls` options.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

What about this trick...

```
ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/{*,.*}

OR

ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/*
```

I think this has problems with empty directories but if another poster has a tweak I'll update my answer. Also, you may already know this but this is probably be a good candidate for an alias given it's lengthiness.

*[update] added some tweaks based on comments, thanks guys.*

*[update] as pointed out by the comments you may need to tweek the matcher expressions depending on the shell (bash vs zsh). I've re-added my older command for reference.*

Comment: After your update the command does not work anymore for me. Message `cannot access /mydir/mysubdir/{*,.*}: No such file or directory`

Comment: `.*` seems to match `.` and `..` on bash, but not on zsh. (`ls -A` doesn't show them, so my previous suggestion only fully works on zsh, and maybe even then my .zshrc has something to do with it)

Comment: One more thing: `ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/{*,.[^.]*}` would not show `.` and `..` in sh, but in zsh shows dot-files twice. There `$PWD/*` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: Another challenge: you can't use wildcard filter, right? What if I want to see `ls -Artl *.log` with full path?

Comment: you *could* wrap in a tiny shell script that changes the $PWD/* part. But that's probably for a different question.

Comment: I made an alias for the command, and now I use the alias all the time

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to downvote this answer... but now I can't change it. Anyway... this works, especially the second form. The first form seems extravagant.

Comment: it works! Could you add more detail into the syntax of the command?

Answer (score 40):

Try this, works for me: `ls -d /a/b/c/*`

Comment: But not **display full path**, try `ls -d .|more` in any place, shows only `.`.

Comment: This works for me: `ls -d $(pwd)/*`

Answer (score 17):

Use this command:

```
ls -ltr /mig/mthome/09/log/*
```

instead of:

```
ls -ltr /mig/mthome/09/log
```

to get the full path in the listing.

Comment: I like this solution better for its simplicity and ease of use. I suppose the other solution might be usable if you created an alias out of it, but realistically, nobody is going to bother to type all that in.

Comment: **Not display the full path**, try `ls -ltr . |more` in any place, shows only filenames, not absolute paths.

Comment: I like this solution, too because most of the other solutions on SO assumes the PO wants to ls the $PWD.. The key is really to list * inside the target directory instead of the directory alone. @PeterKrauss the emphasis is not on -ltr but it's on the glob *. Using your example, it would need to be  ls -ltr *|more.

Answer (score 8):

I use this command:

```
ls -1 | xargs readlink -f
```

Comment: Depending on your file names might need to do `ls -Q1 | xargs readlink -f` But this worked great for me.

Comment: that's a great solution, but what's the difference from a simple `readlink -f`?

Comment: you must have xargs aliased on your machine as 'xargs -L 1'. otherwise this doesn't work for more than one file. the command, in that case is `\ls -1 | xargs -L 1 readlink -f`

Comment: This is the **only answer** that really **display the full path** (absolute paths)!

Comment: on macOS, use the homebrew package `coreutils` (likely already installed) which will install `greadlink` instead.

Comment: This just sticks your CWD in front, e.g. if you ls /other/path while you are /somewhere, it will list for you the files under /other/path as though they are under /somewhere/. Bad answer IMO.

Answer (score 5):

optimized from spacedrop answer ...

```
ls $(pwd)/*
```

and you can use ls options

```
ls -alrt $(pwd)/*
```

Comment: backticks ```` are discourage now and new way to to command substitution is to use `$()`

Comment: @Kiwy ok !  doing this we get  Andrew White 's answer (wich is very nice I agree)

Answer (score 1):

simply use find tool.

find absolute_path

displays full paths on my Linux machine, while

find relative_path

will not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I used `find "/media/lubuntu/mount point/folder/"`. I used `find "/media/lubuntu/mount point/folder/" | grep "pattern"` to find the files I wanted. Any time I used that `$PWD/*` method as other user suggested it gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shell script called **fullpath** that contains this code, use it everyday:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    for i in $* ; do
        echo $(pwd)/$i
    done
```

Put it somewhere in your PATH, and make it executable(chmod 755 fullpath) then just use
**fullpath** *file_or_directory*

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the find command and the ls command. Use the path (.) and selector (*) to narrow down the files you're after. Surround the find command in back quotes. The argument to -name is doublequote star doublequote in case you can't read it.

```
ls -lart `find . -type f -name "*" `
```