# How can I ALIAS --> "less" the latest file in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Just wondering how could I `less` the latest log file in a directory in Linux?
I'm after a oneliner, possibly considering an alias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ls -1dtr /your/dir/{*,.*} | tail -1 | xargs less
```

Note that for the first block of `ls` I am using an answer of [Unix ls command: show full path when using options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580868/1983854)

As it requires a parameter, we create a function instead of an alias. Store the following in `~/.bashrc`:

```
my_less_func ()
{
        ls -1dtr "$1"/{*,.*} | tail -1 | xargs less
}
```

Source it (it is enough doing `. ~/.bashrc`) and call it with:

```
my_less_func your/path
```

Comment: that will first less the output of /yourdir
`230304: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--: No such file or directory`
...and so on...
an alias might be tricky then

Comment: @sponger sure, I just updated my answer. Try it, should work properly now for any directory.

Comment: Nice to read it worked to you! For completeness I  added the alias part.

Comment: Technically, this is a function, not an alias.

Comment: changed this to `ls -1trA /path/to/dir/* | tail -1 | xargs less` to avoid `.` and `..`

Answer (score 1):

In zsh: `less dir/*(.om[1])`

`dir/*` is a regular glob.

The `.` qualifier restricts to regular files.

`om` means order by modification time, newest first.

`[1]` means just expand the first filename.

It's probably better without the `[1]` - just pass all the filenames to `less` in the `om` order. If the first one satisfies you, you can hit `q` and be done with it. If not, the next one is just a `:n` away, or you can search them all with `/*something`. If there are too many, `om[1,10]` will get you 10 newest files.